# Howto email notifications from your web application

Tags: security, cloud, email-notifications

What is the correct way to setup mail notifications from your web app in the cloud era? Previously I always had some SMTP server, which I could use for that purpose, but this time my company mail is hosted and there is a limit of 500 mails per day sent from certain address in this system, so with rather high chances I can hit that limit. My first thought was to use services like sendpulse or mailchimp, but it seems that all these services are built having mass marketing campaigns in mind and I'm concerned about security in case of sensitive emails, like password restore or details about orders. I spent several hours searching for solution in the web, but did not find anything reasonable.

Ideally the service I'm looking for would guarantee, that content of my messages would never be stored or shown to anyone, besides email this service might also be able to send SMS (for password restore case) and have integration with messengers.

Comment: "What is the correct way to..." In software development, there's never one correct way to do anything. Perhaps there's an exception, I can't think of one offhand.

Comment: But as far as StackOverflow is concerned, questions asking for recommendation for services or libraries etc., are closed.

Comment: well, but there are definitely incorrect ways - e.g. doing something that would leak sensitive information; my demand seem to be quite trivial and all I need - a little guidance where to look for solution

Comment: Yes, and in general emailing is about as secure as writing your message on the back of a postcard and mailing it. Unless of course you encrypt it.

Comment: Not exactly, putting postcard in the envelope is a much closer analogy, as ssl channels are a standard de facto; anyway, majority of services send sensitive emails and I definitely not the one to change this, my intent is not to make things worse.

Unless I find any other solution, I would set up my own SMPT server, but I hope there is a way to avoid doing that

Comment: SSL channels are point to point. Admins of the various SMTP servers will be able to read your email. Realistically they probably won't just because of the volume, but they could.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.